# Disable Token Authentication for REST Services in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, authentication, token

For test purposes I have activated Token Authentication through my ArcGIS Server.

Now I want to get back to Windows Authentication and I just simply can't find anywhere clear instructions to disable Token Authentication from the REST Admin side of it? Nor even with ArcGIS community/blogs.

Comment: Windows authentication is a special configuration step, not a default to which you need to be returned. I don't think token authentication can be removed at all; it's just a way to script administrative manipulation of the server instance.